# How to completely disable the Junk folder on Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I am not satisfied with Microsoft's spam filter. I want to completely disable it, i.e., I want every email that is sent to me to go to my Inbox. How can I do this on Outlook.com?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you can simply create a mail filter on Outlook that moves all files in Junk into your main Inbox as a workaround. The steps are as follows:

1. Click on the gear icon on near the top right corner in Outlook.com
2. Click on the "options" menu item
3. Select "Inbox and sweep rule" on the sidebar
4. Click on the + symbol to add a new rule
5. On the "When a message arrives..." option, select the "It was sent or received" from the dropdown, then select "Sent to".
6. Afterwards type in your own email address and press Ok
7. On the "Do the following" option, select the "Move, copy or delete" then the "Move the message to folder..." options from the dropdown menu
8. Choose your inbox as the destination, then click Ok.
9. Finally click Ok again to save the rule.

For more detailed steps with illustrations, feel free to open the link below to the original article.

Source: https://www.wintips.org/how-to-disable-junk-email-filter-in-outlook-com-and-office365-web-app/